# Tree-based methods - performance on datasets with many categorical variables

Tags: classification, categorical-data, random-forest, cart, boosting

Suppose we have a dataset where the majority of the features are categorical. Do tree-based methods (such as decision trees, random forests and boosting) generally outperform other classification models on such a dataset?

I am aware of [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/95212/improve-classification-with-many-categorical-variables) question that discusses some of the potential computational advantages of using tree-based methods with categorical variables. My question is about accuracy/precision and not  concerned with computational time.